# I was trying to import data from a json file but it generates "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error the json file looks like this

Tags: python, json

```
[
    {
        "SALE_PRICE": "$699.95"
    },
    {
     "SALE_PRICE": "$89.95"
    },
    {
    "SALE_PRICE": "$399.95"
    },
    {
    "SALE_PRICE": "$969.95"
    },
    {
    "SALE_PRICE": "$1,563.42"
    },
    {
    "SALE_PRICE": "$299.95"
    },
    {
       "SALE_PRICE": null
    },
    {
    "SALE_PRICE": "$429.95"
    },
    {
    "ORIGINAL_PRICE": null
    },
    {
    "SALE_PRICE": "$529.95"
    }
]
```

Code from OP comment on an answer:

> this is the whole code i used

`from tkinter import * 
import json 
data = ""
priceList = ""
with open('C:\RecoveryImage\\data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data) 
data = json.dumps(data, indent=1) 
priceList = data[0]["SALE_PRICE"] 
root = Tk() 
root.title("Price Viewer") 
Display = Frame(root) 
Display.pack()
text = Label(Display, text= data) text.pack()
root.mainloop()`

Comment: null isn't a type in python. You can change those to None or put quotes around them "null"

Comment: True, but null is a JS representation of Python's None, this is not the issue. I'm leaning towards the subsequent processing of the imported data

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [ask]. You need to add your actual code and the associated stack trace. Please refer to [mcve]

Comment: i tried it but is still generated the same error. i even tried deleting the null entries still wont do. maybe is it because of the code?

Comment: @jonathan And we have no way to help you unless you post it so we can take a look. Please review [mcve]

Comment: how are you "trying to import data"? What function(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first convert the string to equivalent json structure

```
import json

data = json.loads(file_data)
print data[0]["SALE_PRICE"] #Will now print the value
```

Also, i can see that you have used "null" .

Use "None" the python equivalent of "null" in the file.

Comment: that is the code i used. this is the whole code i used from tkinter import *
import json

data = ""
priceList = ""

with open('C:\RecoveryImage\\data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=1)
    priceList = data[0]["SALE_PRICE"]


root = Tk()
root.title("Price Viewer")

Display = Frame(root)
Display.pack()

text = Label(Display, text= data)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()   But it still generates the same error.

Comment: @jonathan Please edit your question to include your code, formatted so that it's readable. AND add the stack trace and full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formatted version of the relevant code, with annotations by me:

```
from tkinter import *
import json
data = "" ### redundant statement
priceList = "" ### redundant statement
with open('C:\RecoveryImage\\data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data) ### This 'data' refers to a list of dicts.
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=1) ### This statement is the culprit.
    priceList = data[0]["SALE_PRICE"] ### Expecting `data` to be a list of dicts, not a str
    root = Tk() # etc etc
```

All that statement does is to produce a (hopefully) syntactically identical copy of the original `json_data` and not use it. Unfortunately it also causes `data` to refer to that redundant information.

Either delete the culprit line, or make it start with `json_data_2 =` instead of `data =`.